# Angular typescript matrix with select all option and saving data

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a dynamically generated matrix (Please see the image):
[Matrix for step and interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dizg6.png)

```
<table class="k-grid">
  <tr class="k-alt">
     <td>Step</td>
     <td>Select All</td>
     <td *ngFor="let aoi of interestList; let i = index" style="text-align:center">{{ aoi.description }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="k-alt">
     <td></td>
     <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td *ngFor="let aoi of interestList; let i = index" style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let step of stepList; let i = index; let odd = odd;" [ngClass]="{ 'k-alt': odd}">
     <td style="text-align:left">{{ step.stepName }}</td>
     <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
     <td *ngFor="let aoi of interestList; let i = index" style="text-align:center">
         <div *ngIf="step.evalByInterest">
            <input type="checkbox" />
         </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My typescript code:

```
this.service.getInterest().subscribe(interest => {
        this.interestList = interest;
    });

this.service.getSteps().subscribe(step => {
        this.stepList = step;
    });
```

I need the select all feature to work.  When I check the red all checkboxes are checked, blue check all will select all steps for that interest and orange check all will check all interest for that step.

Also, when I submit I need a list with selected step and interest (2 dimensional array) to save what the user selected.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are asking for? You say "I need the select all feature to work", but is there a problem with it that you can share an error for? Or are you asking StackOverflow members to give you the entire implementation?

Comment: I've used [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll();" on my blue Checkboxes and [(ngModel)]="step.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected();" on my orange checkboxes - but the when I would click one of the blue checkbox - it would check all blue checkboxes - that is the reason I had removed that from my code and am asking users if they have any suggestions on how to implement check all feature in a dynamic matrix